# Round up results of division to next integer number in c

Tags: c

I make code to display multiple pages (max. 5 lines/page) with persons from one list:

```
/* PRE:     page : number of the page we want to show, starting with 1
 * RETURNS: pagenumber of the page showing if there is one, 0 otherwise  */


const int buf_length = 255;
const int max_num_lines = 15;
const int num_person_per_page = max_num_lines / 3;
const int num_person = person_get_num_person(personmgr);
char buf[buf_length+1];
int i, count, cur = 0;

/* List Header */ 
snprintf(buf, buf_length, "List of person on page (%d/%d)):", page, num_person/num_person_per_page);
list_set_text( list, cur++, buf);
list_set_hilight(list, -1);
```

If list have number of persons witch isn't multiples of 5 (72 - in my example), list header of last page returns total number of page as 14 instead of 15 (14/15).

First page list header:

```
List of person on page: 1/14:
01. AAA
02. BBB
03. CCC
04. DDD
05. EEE
```

Second page list header:

```
List of person on page: 2/14:
06. FFF
07. GGG
08. HHH
........................
```

Last page list header:

```
List of person on page: 14/15:
71. XXX
72. ZZZ
```

I want a to round up to next integer number (pages number to be displayed correctly).

```
72 / 5 = 14.4 => 15
70 / 5 = 14   => 14
36 / 5 = 7.2  => 8
```

First page list header:

```
List of person on page: 1/15:
01. AAA
02. BBB
03. CCC
04. DDD
05. EEE
```

Second page list header:

```
List of person on page: 2/15:
06. FFF
07. GGG
08. HHH
........................
```

Last page list header:

```
List of person on page: 15/15:
71. XXX
72. ZZZ
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write `(n + 4) / 5` to integrally compute the mathematical ceiling of n / 5: If `n` is already a multiple of 5 then you're adding `4 / 5 == 0`, and otherwise you're adding `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Include the `math.h` file and use its [`ceil()`](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/ceil.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
(num_person/num_person_per_page) + ((num_person % num_person_per_page) ? 1 : 0);
```

Perhaps a little more understandable. Adds 1 if the modulus is not zero.

Comment: To me, @Kerrek's way is more understandable. But then, I'm weird, so +1 for this too.

Comment: I used to do it like this, too, but was recently alerted to the method in my answer, which does essentially the same: the result of the added "`4/5`" is "conditional" on the remainder of the other division, if you will. It's just all rolled into one. Or, if you will, the `+4` changes "floor" to "ceiling".

Comment: @Kerrek I like your way too, I will probably steal it if I have a performance-critical piece of code as it will be a lot faster (1 extra addition, and 1 extra subtraction in a real-world case, as opposed to an extra divide, multiply, subtraction and addition for this method.) But my "peers" aren't always the sharpest lot, so if I used it outside of it's own function I'd probably have to add a comment explaining what it does, or I'd certainly have to explain it out loud during a code review ;)

Comment: @Gerald: Sounds like a golden opportunity to shine and cut to the front of the promotion queue! ("He's that geek how knows math...")