# Howto round numbers upwards to the next integer

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round up results of division to next integer number in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881529/round-up-results-of-division-to-next-integer-number-in-c)

Is there a function that rounds a `double` up to the next integer?

```
1.8 -> 2
1.01 ->2
0.99 ->1
```

Comment: What if the value is 2? Should it return 2 or 3?

Comment: -1 "...does not show any research effort..." <math.h> is a good place to look for this sort of thing. `apropos round` would lead you to the right answer. And Googling for 'c rounding function' also gets you to the right function. Please don't use SO as your first stop in looking for an answer -- make an effort to find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [`std::floor()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) and [`std::ceil()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) in C++

Answer (score 2):

ceil(double x) returns the next integral that is not lower than x

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/ceil/

Answer (score 1):

[`std::ceil()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) seems to be what you're looking for - Computes nearest integer not less than arg.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ceil(input)
```

or

```
floor(1+input);
```

Answer (score 1):

basic functions are `ceil`, `floor`, `trunc`; I suppose `ceil` would be your choice.